# What are the charasteristic and minimal polynomial of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say that $A$ is an endomorphism with only one eigenvalue; $\rho$. Then, the charasteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ are as follows:
$$p_A(\lambda)=(-1)^n(\lambda - \rho)^n$$
$$m_A(\lambda) = (\lambda - \rho)^m$$

$B$ is defined as: $B=A-\rho I$

My question is, how do we conclude that the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $B$ are as follows:
$$ p_B(\lambda) = (-1)^n\lambda^n $$
$$ m_B(\lambda) = \lambda^m $$

My professor, during the derivation of Jordan Canonical form, simply stated this fact saying it is obvious, but I can not see why exactly it is true.

Also, why is $B^m = 0$, but $B^k \neq 0$ for $k < m$?

Comment: Show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Well, the problem is I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Just use the definition of an eigenvalue and the fact that $B=A-\rho I$.

Comment: @Servaes Ok, I can show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue. Then, I assume, I can conclude that because $B$ has the same dimension as $A$, $p_B = (-1)^n \lambda^n$. But what about the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @Servaes 

1) I assume it because $B$ has the same dimension as $A$, that's why I believe algebraic multiplicity should be the same: $n$.

2) The definition is it's the non-zero polynomial, for which $m(A)=0$, it's leading coefficient is $1$ and any polynomial $q$ of smaller degree has the property $q(A) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Servaes thanks for nothing except rudeness

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Let $v$ be an eigenvector for $B$ then we have for definition $B(v)=\lambda$v$=A(v)-\rho v$ can you conclude anything from here?

For the second point you can reach a contradiction working on the minimal poly of $A$.